# yii2 override batchinsert from database class

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I want to override batchinsert, because I want to add `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

```
$result = Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->batchInsert('product', ['asin', 'title', 'image', 'url', 'price'], $results)->execute();


public function batchInsert($table, $columns, $rows)
{

    if (empty($rows)) {
        return '';
    }

    $schema = $this->db->getSchema();
    if (($tableSchema = $schema->getTableSchema($table)) !== null) {
        $columnSchemas = $tableSchema->columns;
    } else {
        $columnSchemas = [];
    }

    $values = [];
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $vs = [];
        foreach ($row as $i => $value) {
            if (isset($columns[$i], $columnSchemas[$columns[$i]]) && !is_array($value)) {
                $value = $columnSchemas[$columns[$i]]->dbTypecast($value);
            }
            if (is_string($value)) {
                $value = $schema->quoteValue($value);
            } elseif ($value === false) {
                $value = 0;
            } elseif ($value === null) {
                $value = 'NULL';
            }
            $vs[] = $value;
        }
        $values[] = '(' . implode(', ', $vs) . ')';
    }

    $query = 'INSERT INTO ' . $schema->quoteTableName($table);
    $duplicate = ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ';

    $last = end($columns);
    reset($columns);

    foreach ($columns as $i => $name) {
        $columns[$i] = $schema->quoteColumnName($name);
        $duplicate .= $schema->quoteColumnName($name) . ' = VALUES(' . $schema->quoteColumnName($name) . ')';

        if ($name <> $last) {
            $duplicate .= ', ';
        }
    }

    $query .= ' (' . implode(', ', $columns) . ') ';
    $query .= ' VALUES ' . implode(', ', $values);
    $query .= $duplicate;

    return $query;
}
```

This is working but now I need to override yii\db\QueryBuilder
If found this: `Yii::$app->db->commandClass = new common\models\Command();`

and I can override the command class, but the code in yii\db\Schema should be updated too

```
public function createQueryBuilder()
{
    return new \common\models\QueryBuilder($this->db);
}
```

Or I need to do something completely different, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this discussion about non standard sql commands](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/5138#issuecomment-56640088) of devs you can do following (not tested):

```
class MyQueryBuilder extends yii\db\mysql\QueryBuilder
{
    public function batchInsert($table, $columns, $rows)
    {
        $sql = parent::batchInsert($table, $columns, $rows);
        $sql .= 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE';
        return $sql;
    }
}
```

or you can do this:

```
$db = Yii::$app->db;
$sql = $db->queryBuilder->batchInsert($table, $fields, $rows);
$db->createCommand($sql . ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE')->execute();
```

Comment: thanks, ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is not working for me without  asin = VALUES (
asin
), `title` = VALUES(`title`) etc, but it's working now

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace common\models;

use yii\db\mysql\QueryBuilder as baseQueryBuilder;

class QueryBuilder extends baseQueryBuilder
{
    public function batchInsert($table, $columns, $rows)
    {
        $sql = parent::batchInsert($table, $columns, $rows);
        $sql .= ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ';

        $schema = $this->db->getSchema();
        $last = end($columns);
        reset($columns);

        foreach ($columns as $i => $column)
        {
            $columns[$i] = $schema->quoteColumnName($column);
            $sql .= $schema->quoteColumnName($column) . ' = VALUES(' . $schema->quoteColumnName($column) . ')';

            if ($column <> $last) {
                $sql .= ', ';
            }
        }

        return $sql;
    }
}


$db = Yii::$app->db;
$queryBuilder = new \common\models\QueryBuilder(Yii::$app->db);
$query = $queryBuilder->batchInsert('product', ['asin', 'title', 'image', 'url', 'price'], $results);
$db->createCommand($query)->execute();
```